# Full width gallery in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery gallery in my page, and i want to make it full width to all resolutions and screens.

[The page](http://www.tranceil.co.il/comp/)

jQuery:

```
$('#grid1').dynamicGallery({
                    src : 'gallery.xml',
                    height : 400,
                    width : 1350,
                    cols : 5,
                    min_rows : 1,
                    max_rows : 2,
                    random_heights : false,
                    padding: 1,
                    interval : 2000,
                    speed : 1000,
                    easing : 'easeOutQuad',
                    scale_images : true,
                    center_images : true,
                    click_action : 'lightbox',
                    show_title_in_lightbox : true
                });
```

- I tried giving it a bigger width as you can see but its going to the
  right of the page, when centering the div with css it still appears
  differently on other screens.

Comment: `.shell` has a width of 800px and margin: 0 auto; make that 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Two problems.

1. I never defined `viewportwidth` and `viewportheight`. Gotta do that.
2. You don't need a function. Just define the two variables and put the code without the function in the `<head>` section of the page. Then, of course, remove the `<body onload="resize()">` and just put `<body>`.

Done. The final code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title>Dynamic Grid</title>

    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" value="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tranceil.co.il/comp/css/layout.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tranceil.co.il/comp/css/dynamic.grid.css" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        .shell > div {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="shell" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div id="grid1"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://www.tranceil.co.il/comp/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.tranceil.co.il/comp/js/dynamic.grid.gallery.js"></script>



    <script>
        var viewportwidth;
    var viewportheight;

    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
    viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
    viewportheight = window.innerHeight
}

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
    viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
}

// older versions of IE

else {
    viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
}

        (function($, undefined) {
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#grid1').dynamicGallery({
                    src : 'http://www.tranceil.co.il/comp/gallery.xml',
                    height : viewportheight,
                    width : viewportwidth,
                    cols : 5,
                    min_rows : 1,
                    max_rows : 2,
                    random_heights : false,
                    padding: 1,
                    interval : 2000,
                    speed : 1000,
                    easing : 'easeOutQuad',
                    scale_images : true,
                    center_images : true,
                    click_action : 'lightbox',
                    show_title_in_lightbox : true
                });

                $('#grid2').dynamicGallery({
                    src : 'http://www.tranceil.co.il/comp/gallery.xml',
                    height : 400,
                    width : 1350,
                    cols : 5,
                    min_rows : 1,
                    max_rows : 4,
                    random_heights : false,


            padding: 1,
                interval : 2000,
                speed : 1000,
                easing : 'easeOutQuad',
                scale_images : true,
                center_images : true,
                click_action : 'lightbox',
                show_title_in_lightbox : true
            });


        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**Original Post:**

Haven't tested this code specifically for your situation, but I think it should work.

```
function resize() {
    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
    viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
    viewportheight = window.innerHeight
}

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
    viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
}

// older versions of IE

else {
    viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
}

}
```

This function will get the height and width of the browser. Replace your `<body>` tag with

```
<body onload="resize()">
```

Then, for your gallery:

```
$('#grid1').dynamicGallery({
                    src : 'gallery.xml',
                    height : viewportheight,
                    width : viewportwidth,
                    cols : 5,
                    min_rows : 1,
                    max_rows : 2,
                    random_heights : false,
                    padding: 1,
                    interval : 2000,
                    speed : 1000,
                    easing : 'easeOutQuad',
                    scale_images : true,
                    center_images : true,
                    click_action : 'lightbox',
                    show_title_in_lightbox : true
                });
```

This should set the gallery height and width to be the same as the viewport, thus filling up 100% of the screen.

Test that and let me know if you have issues.

Comment: Hey buddy, thanx for the code..i'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: viewportheight is not defined ..i'm guessing i didnt put that on the right place?

Comment: I'm looking at your source code and it looks like you put the function in the right place...try putting an alert in the `$(document).ready` function to see if you're getting values for `viewportheight` and `viewportwidth`.

Comment: A "hello" alert works for the gallery code, but not yours...do i need to put $(document).ready in the top of your script?

Comment: Andy's solution was the easy way out to be honest, but i'm intrested on getting your code working..

Comment: I'm looking at the source code right now, gonna try and devise a solution.

Comment: Glad I could help! This was a learning experience for me too xD